# Where to download a list of email accounts hacked from Adobe?

Tags: passwords

Adobe [announced they had been hacked](http://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/policy-pricing/ecc.html) and millions of user accounts and passwords compromised.

These sites allow a search on email address to see if it was compromised:
https://lastpass.com/adobe/
http://adobe.breach.il.ly/

This site contains the Top 100 passwords used:

http://stricture-group.com/files/adobe-top100.txt

Where are they getting this information from?

Where can I download a list of the emails so I can notify any of my site's users, with the same email, to change their password like Facebook have done?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for a link to a particular resource from a particular incident.  Links to this data will likely quickly be invalidated and not helpful to future users, so this is not a good fit for the StackExchange site format. 

Comment: [Have I Been Pwned](https://haveibeenpwned.com/API/v2) from [Troy Hunt](https://troyhunt.com) now offers an API to do must much more effectively that downloading breach data myself. Queenslander!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I could not give you a direct link to the file, but you could search for a file called "users.tar.gz", which has a file size of about 3.8 GB. With the search engine of your choice you should be able to find the file within minutes.